# PowerShell Removing Folder Permission for Deleted AD User Accounts

Tags: powershell, directory, permissions

Once a User is removed in AD their name is changes to a S-X-XX-XXX

I have a script to pull all folders where the S-X-XX-XXX has permissions,  what I am trying to do is take that list of Folders and remove all S-X-XX-XXX's.

Code

```
<# The S-* is to represent the User ID that I am wanting to remove their folder permissions #>
$TargetUser = "S-*"
$TargetPath = "C:\Depts"

$Paths = get-childitem -path $TargetPath -Recurse -Directory
$FolderList = $Paths.FullName

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $Folder
    $ACLlist = $ACL.Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like "*mike*"} 
    $RemoveUser = $ACLlist.IdentityReference

    if ($ACLlist.IdentityReference -like "$TargetUser") {
        Write-Host $Folder
        Write-Host $RemoveUser
        $ACE = New-Object System.Security.Accesscontrol.FileSystemAccessRule($RemoveUser, "None", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Deny")
        $ACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)
        Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $ACL
    }
}
```

I have found code on how to set folder permission from another folders permissions,  however this are users that were not added through inheritance.

I know I am missing something simple so any help would be great.

[Folder Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr2FW.png)

Big thanks to everyone that replied, I appreciate you guys taking the time to help.

Comment: The simple solution: do not remove accounts. Disable the account, move into specific OU and add a prefix of, say, `X_` to the account name.

Comment: What is the code not doing? Once the script finished running, what has changed on the folders? I am just wondering what exactly you are missing on the code.

Comment: vonPryz - the accounts are disabled and removed from the Active Direcrtory.  This is a house cleaning task I am streamline instead of having to go through all the folders and do it manually.

Comment: Alex_P - the accounts are not being removed, or changed at all.  The script above in the variables gives me the FullPath of each folder "C:\Depts\"Fold Name\Sub Folder Name" and the domain\S-X-XX-XXX account.  I can see what permissions that are assign to each S-X-XX-XXX as well with another script I used to recursively check all folders in the folder tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what type of user login in acl, you don't need template.And you must go for each access rule in each folder to check this,because **removeaccesrule** method take only one object at time.

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
$TargetPath = "D:\testdir"
$Paths = get-childitem -path $TargetPath -Recurse -Directory
$FolderList = $Paths.FullName

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    $ACLs = Get-Acl -Path $Folder
    foreach($acl in $ACLs.Access){
        If (($acl.IdentityReference -is [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) -and (-not $acl.IsInherited)){
        Write-Debug ("Removing ACl for {0}`r`n" -f $acl.IdentityReference.Value)
        [Void]$ACLs.RemoveAccessRule($acl)
        }
    }
Write-Debug ("Setting ACL for {0}`r`n" -f $folder.FullName)
Set-Acl -path $folder -aclObject $ACLs
}
```

**I have one more solution:**
Use module ntfsSecurity(folder and files management   [manual](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85))
Lists all permissions that can no longer be resolved. This normally happens if the account is no longer available so the permissions show up as a SID and not as an account name.

To remove all non-resolvable or orphaned permissions you can use the following line. But be very careful with that as maybe the account is not resolvable due to a network problem.

```
Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity
dir -Recurse | Get-NTFSOrphanedAccess | Remove-NTFSAccess
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't not alter the targeted person.  In the test case I do not have a S-X-XX-XXX user so I am attempting to remove a non inherited permission for the account "domain\mikeh".  When I run the code executes there are no errors but nothing changes.  I will post a picture of the folder permission above.

Comment: I check script one more time and it's remove user from folder perfectly.

Comment: I think I know what happened, the target was in the root/target folder and since inheritance being enabled it would not remove them since the root/target folder was not being checked.  I ended up have to add more to the code to get it working for the root/target folder down.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the problem is below.

```
Clear
$TargetUser = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the target account you are targeting [Full or Parital works]"
$RootPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the root folder to start looking in and removing permissions"

$SubPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Recurse -Directory
$SubFolderList = $SubPaths.FullName
$rootdone = $false
$FolderPurgeList = @()

if ($rootdone -eq $false) {
        $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $RootPath
        $ACLlist = $ACL.Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like "*$TargetUser*"} 
        $RemoveUser = $ACLlist.IdentityReference

        $count = $RemoveUser.count 
            ForEach ($UserName in $RemoveUser ) {
                $UserID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount ($UserName)
                $ACL.PurgeAccessRules($UserID)
                $ACL | Set-Acl $RootPath

                $itemHasPerm = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
                    $itemHasPerm | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Target User" -Value $UserName
                    $itemHasPerm | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Folder Path" -Value $RootPath

                $FolderPurgeList += $itemHasPerm
                $count -= 1
        }
    if ($count -eq 0 ) {
    $rootdone = $true
    }
}

if ($rootdone -eq $true) {
    ForEach ($SubFolder in $SubFolderList) {
        $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $SubFolder
        $ACLlist = $ACL.Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like "*$TargetUser*"} 
        $RemoveUser = $ACLlist.IdentityReference
            ForEach ($UserName in $RemoveUser ) {
                $UserID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount ($UserName)
                $ACL.PurgeAccessRules($UserID)
                $ACL | Set-Acl $SubFolder

                $itemHasPerm = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
                    $itemHasPerm | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Target User" -Value $UserName
                    $itemHasPerm | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Folder Path" -Value $SubFolder

                $FolderPurgeList += $itemHasPerm
        }
    }
}

$FolderPurgeList
$DateStamp = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy - hh-ss"
$FolderPurgeList | Export-CSV $env:USERProfile\Documents\Purged_Permission_List_$DateStamp.csv
```